# Getting value from GUI and using it in another class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm trying to get the values from my GUI to be accessible to other classes in my program, I managed to get the values for concA and concB to be usable by the start method in the simulation class but I can't get the temperature value to be usable in the move method of the particle class. Where I have used 10 as a temporary value (line 133 & 134) I want that to be the temperature/100. This is my code in it's working form so far.

```
from tkinter import *
import random, math

class master():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mySim = simulation(self)
        self.myGUI = GUI(self)
        self.myGUI.menu.mainloop()
    def startSim(self, newdata):
        self.mySim.start(newdata)

class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.myMaster = master
        self.menu = Tk()
        self.menu.title("Menu")
        self.createMainGUI()

    def createMainGUI(self):
        #Create Menu
        self.catalyst = Checkbutton(self.menu, text = "Catalyst", anchor = 'w', justify = LEFT)
        self.temperature = Scale(self.menu, from_=0, to=1000, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        self.concA = Scale(self.menu, from_=1, to=50, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        self.concB = Scale(self.menu, from_=1, to=50, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        self.start = Button(self.menu, text="Start", width=5, height=2)
        self.exit = Button(self.menu, text="Exit", width = 5, height=2)
        self.title = Label(self.menu, text = "Chemistry reaction model", width = 20, height = 2)
        self.option = Label(self.menu, text = "Options:", width = 10, height = 2, anchor = 'w', justify = LEFT)
        self.temperaturelabel = Label(self.menu, text = "Temperature in Kelvin:")
        self.concALabel = Label(self.menu, text = "Concentration of A:")
        self.concBLabel = Label(self.menu, text = "Concentration of B:")

        #Format Menu
        self.title.grid(column = 1, row = 1, columnspan = 3)
        self.option.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.catalyst.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
        self.temperature.grid(column = 2, row = 4, columnspan = 2)
        self.concA.grid(column = 2, row = 5, columnspan = 2)
        self.concB.grid(column = 2, row = 6, columnspan = 2)
        self.start.grid(column = 1, row = 7)
        self.exit.grid(column = 2, row = 7)
        self.temperaturelabel.grid(column =1, row = 4)
        self.concALabel.grid(column =1, row = 5)
        self.concBLabel.grid(column =1, row = 6)

        #Event Handlers
        self.start.bind('<Button-1>', self.startSimulationGUI)
        self.exit.bind('<Button-1>', self.quit)

    def update_canvas(self, particles):
        self.canvas.delete('all') #clears canvas and redraws all particles at new positions
        for i in particles:
            self.canvas.create_oval(i.x, i.y, i.x+i.size,i.y+i.size , fill = "red")

    def quit(self, event):
        self.menu.destroy()

    def startSimulationGUI(self, event):
        self.simGUI = Toplevel(master=self.menu)
        self.simGUI.title("Simulation")
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.simGUI)
        self.canvas.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        self.canvas.config(width = 400, height=400, bg = "Ghost White")
        # (0,0) is the top left and  (400, 400) is the bottom right coordinates
        self.Toolbar = LabelFrame(self.simGUI, relief = RAISED, width = 200, height = 50, padx = 105)
        self.Toolbar.grid(column = 0, row =2)
        self.Toolbar.config()

        self.MenuExit = Button(self.Toolbar, text="Quit to Menu")
        self.MenuExit.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.MenuExit.bind('<Button-1>', self.simExit)

        self.time = Label(self.Toolbar, text ="Timer:", padx = 30)
        self.time.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        #Get Data
        newdata = data()
        newdata.temp = self.temperature.get()
        newdata.catalyst = self.catalyst.getint()
        newdata.concA = self.concA.get()
        newdata.concB = self.concB.get()
        self.myMaster.startSim(newdata)

    def simExit(self, event):
        self.simGUI.destroy()
        self.myMaster.mySim.particles.clear() #makes sure that if the user exits, changes the settings and restarts no extra particles are drawn


class simulation():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.particles = []
        self.myMaster = master
        #self.myParticleData = data()
        self.myParticle = particle(0,0)

    def start(self, myParticleData):
        self.myParticleData = myParticleData
        for i in range(0, self.myParticleData.concA):
            self.particles.append(particle(random.randint(0,400),random.randint(0,400)))
        for i in range(0, self.myParticleData.concB):
            self.particles.append(particle(random.randint(0,400),random.randint(0,400)))
        self.myMaster.myGUI.update_canvas(self.particles)
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        for i in self.particles:
            i.walls()
            i.move()
        self.myMaster.myGUI.update_canvas(self.particles)
        self.myMaster.myGUI.menu.after(100, self.animate)

class particle():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        #self.tag = a or b or c
        self.speed = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.myGUI = GUI
        self.size = 5
        self.myParticleData= data()
        #self.hyp = sqrt(self.size**2+self.size**2)

    def move(self):
        self.direction = random.randint(0, 360)
        self.x += math.sin(self.direction) * 10     # USING 10 AS TEMP VALUE
        self.y -= math.cos(self.direction) * 10    # USING 10 AS TEMP VALUE

    def walls(self):
        if self.x > 390 - self.size:
            self.x = 2*(400 - self.size) - self.x
            self.direction = -self.direction

        elif self.x < 10+self.size:
            self.x = 2*self.size - self.x
            self.direction = - self.direction

        if self.y > 390 - self.size:
            self.y = 2*(400 - self.size) - self.y
            self.direction = 180 - self.direction

        elif self.y < 10 + self.size:
            self.y = 2*self.size - self.y
            self.direction = 180 - self.direction

class data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp = None
        self.concA = None
        self.concB = None
        self.catalyst = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = master()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the `particle()` class do that each particle has its own temperature. Changes are followed by `###`, hope this helps.

```
from tkinter import *
import random, math

class master():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mySim = simulation(self)
        self.myGUI = GUI(self)
        self.myGUI.menu.mainloop()
    def startSim(self, newdata):
        self.mySim.start(newdata)

class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.myMaster = master
        self.menu = Tk()
        self.menu.title("Menu")
        self.createMainGUI()

    def createMainGUI(self):
        #Create Menu
        self.catalyst = Checkbutton(self.menu, text = "Catalyst", anchor = 'w', justify = LEFT)
        self.temperature = Scale(self.menu, from_=0, to=1000, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        self.concA = Scale(self.menu, from_=1, to=50, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        self.concB = Scale(self.menu, from_=1, to=50, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        self.start = Button(self.menu, text="Start", width=5, height=2)
        self.exit = Button(self.menu, text="Exit", width = 5, height=2)
        self.title = Label(self.menu, text = "Chemistry reaction model", width = 20, height = 2)
        self.option = Label(self.menu, text = "Options:", width = 10, height = 2, anchor = 'w', justify = LEFT)
        self.temperaturelabel = Label(self.menu, text = "Temperature in Kelvin:")
        self.concALabel = Label(self.menu, text = "Concentration of A:")
        self.concBLabel = Label(self.menu, text = "Concentration of B:")

        #Format Menu
        self.title.grid(column = 1, row = 1, columnspan = 3)
        self.option.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.catalyst.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
        self.temperature.grid(column = 2, row = 4, columnspan = 2)
        self.concA.grid(column = 2, row = 5, columnspan = 2)
        self.concB.grid(column = 2, row = 6, columnspan = 2)
        self.start.grid(column = 1, row = 7)
        self.exit.grid(column = 2, row = 7)
        self.temperaturelabel.grid(column =1, row = 4)
        self.concALabel.grid(column =1, row = 5)
        self.concBLabel.grid(column =1, row = 6)

        #Event Handlers
        self.start.bind('<Button-1>', self.startSimulationGUI)
        self.exit.bind('<Button-1>', self.quit)

    def update_canvas(self, particles):
        self.canvas.delete('all') #clears canvas and redraws all particles at new positions
        for i in particles:
            self.canvas.create_oval(i.x, i.y, i.x+i.size,i.y+i.size , fill = "red")

    def quit(self, event):
        self.menu.destroy()

    def startSimulationGUI(self, event):
        self.simGUI = Toplevel(master=self.menu)
        self.simGUI.title("Simulation")
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.simGUI)
        self.canvas.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        self.canvas.config(width = 400, height=400, bg = "Ghost White")
        # (0,0) is the top left and  (400, 400) is the bottom right coordinates
        self.Toolbar = LabelFrame(self.simGUI, relief = RAISED, width = 200, height = 50, padx = 105)
        self.Toolbar.grid(column = 0, row =2)
        self.Toolbar.config()

        self.MenuExit = Button(self.Toolbar, text="Quit to Menu")
        self.MenuExit.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.MenuExit.bind('<Button-1>', self.simExit)

        self.time = Label(self.Toolbar, text ="Timer:", padx = 30)
        self.time.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        #Get Data
        newdata = data()
        newdata.temp = self.temperature.get()
        newdata.catalyst = self.catalyst.getint()
        newdata.concA = self.concA.get()
        newdata.concB = self.concB.get()
        newdata.temperature = self.temperature.get() ###
        self.myMaster.startSim(newdata)

    def simExit(self, event):
        self.simGUI.destroy()
        self.myMaster.mySim.particles.clear() #makes sure that if the user exits, changes the settings and restarts no extra particles are drawn


class simulation():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.particles = []
        self.myMaster = master
        #self.myParticleData = data()
        #self.myParticle = particle(0,0) ###

    def start(self, myParticleData):
        self.myParticleData = myParticleData
        for i in range(0, self.myParticleData.concA):
            self.particles.append(particle(random.randint(0,400),random.randint(0,400),self.myParticleData.temperature)) ###
        for i in range(0, self.myParticleData.concB):
            self.particles.append(particle(random.randint(0,400),random.randint(0,400),self.myParticleData.temperature)) ###
        self.myMaster.myGUI.update_canvas(self.particles)
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        for i in self.particles:
            i.walls()
            i.move()
        self.myMaster.myGUI.update_canvas(self.particles)
        self.myMaster.myGUI.menu.after(100, self.animate)

class particle():
    def __init__(self, x, y, temp): ###
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.temp = temp ###
        #self.tag = a or b or c
        self.speed = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.myGUI = GUI
        self.size = 5
        self.myParticleData= data()
        #self.hyp = sqrt(self.size**2+self.size**2)

    def move(self):
        self.direction = random.randint(0, 360)
        self.x += math.sin(self.direction) * .1 * self.temp     ###
        self.y -= math.cos(self.direction) * .1 * self.temp     ###

    def walls(self):
        if self.x > 390 - self.size:
            self.x = 2*(400 - self.size) - self.x
            self.direction = -self.direction

        elif self.x < 10+self.size:
            self.x = 2*self.size - self.x
            self.direction = - self.direction

        if self.y > 390 - self.size:
            self.y = 2*(400 - self.size) - self.y
            self.direction = 180 - self.direction

        elif self.y < 10 + self.size:
            self.y = 2*self.size - self.y
            self.direction = 180 - self.direction

class data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp = None
        self.concA = None
        self.concB = None
        self.catalyst = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = master()
```